# Is callback function essentially a function inside another function?

Tags: javascript

why is this wrong:

```
markImportant({ Id: this.row.Id })
          .then(this.showToast("success"))
          .catch(this.showToast("error"));
```

And this is right?

```
markImportant({ Id: this.row.Id })
      .then(() => {
          this.showToast("success");
      })
      .catch(() => {
          this.showToast("error");
      });
```

I'm passing a function as a paremeter in both cases. The first case is only one function, whereas the second function is a function inside another function as a parameter.

Comment: In the first, you are calling `this.showToast()` and then passing the return value of `showToast()` as the first argument to `.then()` (`showToast()` being called immediatly). In the second example, you are passing `.then()` a function `() => {}` which when invoked will call your your `showToast()` method

Comment: A callback is a function that is meant to be called **later**

Comment: Aha, okay, thank you very much friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `.then(this.showToast("success"))` you are invoking the `showToast` function which i believe it returns undefined so you can't invoke `undefined`

in `then(() => { this.showToast("success")})` you are passing a function which can be invoked so thats why that works